# Vb.net, replace any number at the end of a string with a placeholder

Tags: vb.net, replace, numeric

I have many strings that have numbers at the end. The numbers can be of any size, for example:

```
myvar123
mysecondvar3
mythirdvar219107
```

The strings can have numbers even inside the name, not only at the end. 
for example:

```
my2varable123
some123variable9480395
```

I would need to replace any number at the END with a placeholder. (NOT those inside the varname.)

for example:

```
my2varable123            should become:   my2variable%placeholder%
some123variable9480395   should become:   some123variable%placeholder%
```

The only way that comes to my mind is to go through the string using .right() and remove the char if it is numeric until I find the first non numeric char. Then in the end append the placeholder, but it looks like a lot of work for a rather simply problem.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a Regex for this.

```
Dim str As String = "some123variable9480395"
Dim pattern As String = "\d+$"
Dim replacement As String = "%placeholder%"
Dim rgx As Regex = New Regex(pattern)
Dim result As String = rgx.Replace(str, replacement)
```